# Ошибка при запуске tomcat приложения на VPS

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, vps

Написал небольшое приложение на Java (Spring MVC) которое запускаю с помощью Tomcat из Intellij IDEA. Получил VPS сервер (Ubuntu 14.04), установил на нем томкат (страница Tomcat Web Application Manager работает), залил проект в директорию /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ и в менеджере томката появился url моего приложения [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
но когда перехожу на этот url получаю

> HTTP Status 404 - /YaPokupay/
>
> description The requested resource is not available.

Локально на localhost все нормально запускалось.

*Если необходима дополнительная информация по теме - с радостью предоставлю.*

На всякий случай web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <filter>
        <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
        </filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/appconfig-root.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!--Security-->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

     Processes application requests
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/appconfig-mvc.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

</web-app>
```

РЕДАКТИРОВАНО:

/var/log/tomcat7/catalina.log

```
Dec 20, 2016 2:24:04 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Dec 20, 2016 2:24:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Dec 20, 2016 2:24:05 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Dec 20, 2016 2:24:05 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Dec 20, 2016 2:24:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/common/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Dec 20, 2016 2:24:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/common], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Dec 20, 2016 2:24:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/server/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Dec 20, 2016 2:24:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/server], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Dec 20, 2016 2:24:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/shared/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Dec 20, 2016 2:24:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/shared], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Dec 20, 2016 2:24:06 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Dec 20, 2016 2:24:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 490 ms
Dec 20, 2016 2:24:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Dec 20, 2016 2:24:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 (Ubuntu)
Dec 20, 2016 2:24:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/host-manager.xml
Dec 20, 2016 2:24:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/docs.xml
Dec 20, 2016 2:24:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml
Dec 20, 2016 2:24:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/YaPokupay
Dec 20, 2016 2:24:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT
Dec 20, 2016 2:24:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Dec 20, 2016 2:24:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1228 ms
Dec 20, 2016 2:24:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/YaPokupay] has started
Dec 20, 2016 2:24:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/YaPokupay] is completed
```

/var/log/tomcat7/localhost 2016-12-20.log

```
Dec 20, 2016 2:24:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: init: Associated with Deployer 'Catalina:type=Deployer,host=localhost'
Dec 20, 2016 2:24:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: init: Global resources are available
Dec 20, 2016 2:24:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
Dec 20, 2016 2:24:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
Dec 20, 2016 2:24:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: restart: Reloading web application '/YaPokupay'
Dec 20, 2016 2:24:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.ya.pokupay</groupId>
    <artifactId>YaPokupay</artifactId>
    <name>YaPokupay</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java-version>1.8</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>4.0.3.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.spring-data-version>1.8.2.RELEASE</org.spring-data-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.7.4</org.aspectj-version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>
        <jackson.version>2.5.3</jackson.version>
        <logback.version>1.1.3</logback.version>
        <javax.mail-version>1.4.7</javax.mail-version>
        <velocity-version>1.7</velocity-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.directory.studio</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.commons.io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Mail-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring MVC Mail Related Dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.mail-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>${velocity-version}</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- Spring ORM -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Spring Security-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Hibernate Search-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.Final</version>
            <!--<version>5.5.5.Final</version>-->
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Commons DBCP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Data JPA-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${org.spring-data-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Jackson-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--File Upload-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version> <!-- make sure correct version here -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
            <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
           
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <!--<configuration>-->
                    <!--<url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>-->
                    <!--<server>YaPokupay</server>-->
                    <!--<path>/</path>-->
                <!--</configuration>-->
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <assembleDirectory>target</assembleDirectory>
                    <programs>
                        <program>
                            <mainClass>com/ya/pokupay/MainController</mainClass>
                            <name>webapp</name>
                        </program>
                    </programs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>assemble</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Структура:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

facets->web in IDEA:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

deployment:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

artifact:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51293/discussion-on-question-by-dmitry----tomcat---vps).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в несоответствии версий java на VPS и локальной машине. Для решения необходимо произвести следующие действия:

1. удалить java на ПК и на сервере
2. скачать последнюю версию jdk с  [официального сайта](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)
3. установить эту версию на ПК и на сервере (инструкции есть в интернете, например [здесь](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/install_overview.html))
4. далее в файле /etc/init.d/tomcat7 в строчке c `JDK_DIRS` указываем путь к ранее установленной jdk, у меня установлена здесь: `JDK_DIRS="/opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_112"`
5. перезапускаем томкат
6. радуемся